# node-sass cli not compiling on initial run when using --watch

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

So when running the following command I'm expecting node-sass to compile and start watching. If I have to run a separate node-sass -w command wouldn't I have to include all the same parameters I included on the first? Seems like an odd way of doing things.

```
node-sass app/styles -o app/styles --source-map true --include-path app/bower_components --quiet --watch
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `watch` triggers compilation each and every time the file changes, as the [(sass) documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) states:

> You can also tell Sass to watch the file and update the CSS every time the Sass file changes: [...]

However, the documentation says nothing about what happens when the `watch` process starts, which is what led you to expect it to compile right after being invoked. 

 It's, for sure, an odd way of doing things.